# QAD QGIS Polyline changes its position

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I started using QAD plugin in QGIS, and try to create a polyline, based on the image of the Openlayers background map. After I finish digitizing the polyline and try to zoom in or out, it changes its actual position. Both the new layer and the map have the same spatial coordinates.
[image] The first picture is from the digitizing, and is in the right place
[image] And this one is after I zoom-out the image

Comment: The OpenLayers plugin has been buggy in the past, especially with shifting layers. Try using a base layer from the plugin QuickMapServices.

Comment: If the lines were digitized from a faulty base layer, you'll have to correct them once you get a correct base layer in place.

Comment: I found out what the problem was. I was using Stereo 70 both for canvas and layer, and Google Maps uses WGS 84. When I switched back to WGS 84, they stopped moving.